# Separate Bayesian parameter estimates for multiple groups in JAGS/rjags

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, runjags

I am trying to perform a hierarchical analysis in JAGS, extrapolating from Kruschke's Doing Bayesian Data Analysis, chapter 9. I wish to obtain posterior parameter estimates for the proportion of heads for four coins (theta's 1,2,3 and 4), coming from two mints, and also the estimates for average bias of the coins that come from each mint (mint bias: omega). I have kept the variability of each mint's bias, kappa, as a constant. The trouble is that I cannot get a posterior estimate from the second mint, it seems to just be sampling the prior. Does anyone know how to fix the model string text (see step 3 below) so as to generate the posterior estimate for the second mint?

Entire script for the analysis below

```
library(rjags)
library(runjags)
library(coda)


############### 1. Generate the data 

flips <- c(sample(c(rep(1,3), rep(0,9))), # coin 1, mint 1, 12 flips total
           sample(c(rep(1,1), rep(0,4))), # coin 2, mint 1, 5 flips total
           sample(c(rep(1,10), rep(0,5))), # coin 1, mint 2, 15 flips
           sample(c(rep(1,17), rep(0,6)))) # coin 2, mint 2, 23 flips

coins <- factor(c(rep(1,12), rep(2,5), rep(3, 15), rep(4, 23)))

mints <- factor(c(rep(1,17), rep(2,38)))

nFlips <- length(flips) 
nCoins <- length(unique(coins))
nMints <- length(unique(mints))


#################### 2. Pass data into a list 

dataList <- list(
  flips = flips,
  coins = coins,
  mints = mints,
  nFlips = nFlips,
  nCoins = nCoins,
  nMints = nMints)


################### 3. specify and save the model 

modelString <- "
model{

      # start with nested likelihood function
      for (i in 1:nFlips) {

              flips[i] ~ dbern(theta[coins[i]])
      } 

      # next the prior on theta
      for (coins in 1:nCoins) {

              theta[coins] ~ dbeta(omega[mints[coins]]*(kappa - 2) + 1, (1 - omega[mints[coins]])*(kappa - 2) + 1) 
      }

      # next we specify the prior for the higher-level parameters on the mint, omega and kappa
      for (mints in 1:nMints) {

              omega[mints] ~ dbeta(2,2)

      }

      kappa <- 5
}
"


writeLines(modelString, "tempModelHier4CoinTwoMint.txt")

############################### Step 4: Initialise Chains 

initsList <- list(theta1 = mean(flips[coins==1]),
                  theta2 = mean(flips[coins==2]),
                  theta3 = mean(flips[coins==3]),
                  theta4 = mean(flips[coins==4]),
                  omega1 = mean(c(mean(flips[coins==1]),
                                 mean(flips[coins==2]))),
                  omega2 = mean(c(mean(flips[coins==3]),
                                 mean(flips[coins==4]))))

initsList


############################### Step 5: Generate Chains 

runJagsOut <- run.jags(method = "simple",
                       model = "tempModelHier4CoinTwoMint.txt",
                       monitor = c("theta[1]", "theta[2]", "theta[3]", "theta[4]", "omega[1]", "omega[2]"),
                       data = dataList,
                       inits = initsList,
                       n.chains = 1,
                       adapt = 500,
                       burnin = 1000,
                       sample = 50000,
                       thin = 1,
                       summarise = FALSE,
                       plots = FALSE)



############################### Step 6: Convert to Coda Object 

codaSamples <- as.mcmc.list(runJagsOut)

head(codaSamples)


############################### Step 7: Make Graphs 

df <- data.frame(as.matrix(codaSamples))

theta1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$theta.1.)) + geom_density()
theta2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$theta.2.)) + geom_density()
theta3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$theta.3.)) + geom_density()
theta4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$theta.4.)) + geom_density()
omega1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$omega.1.)) + geom_density()
omega2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = df$omega.2.)) + geom_density()

require(gridExtra)

ggsave("coinsAndMintsHier/hierPropFourCoinsTwoMints.pdf", grid.arrange(theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, omega1, omega2, ncol = 2), device = "pdf", height = 30, width = 10, units = "cm")
```

Comment: I don't have time to check right now, but I wonder if the use of `coins` twice, once as data and once as the index of the second for-loop, might be causing some trouble?

Comment: Thank you @ Jacob Socolar, but `coins` is not data, it is a factor that indexes the coin number. `flips` is the data.

Comment: Your dataList defines a variable named `coins` as data.

Comment: As Jacob Socolar says, the script uses `coins` as both a for-loop index and a data vector. Notice in the model specification: `for (coins in 1:nCoins)`. Change the loop index to a different name, such as `cIdx` everywhere it occurs. Don't know if that will solve the problem, but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @John K. Kruschke. Unfortunately it has had no effect. The posterior for what should be the first mint is an estimation based on all four coins instead of just the first two, and what should be the graph of the posterior for the second mint is clearly still sampling  directly from the prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the way you were attempting to index the mints of the coins when setting the prior on `theta`. There are only 4 `theta`'s in this case, not `nFlips`. Your nested indexing `mints[coins]` was accessing the `mints` data vector, not a vector of which mint each coin belongs to. I've created a corrected version below. Notice the explicit construction of a vector that indexes which mint each coin belongs to. Notice also in the model specification each for-loop index has its own index name distinct from data names.

```
graphics.off() # This closes all of R's graphics windows.
rm(list=ls())  # Careful! This clears all of R's memory!

library(runjags)
library(coda)

#library(rjags)

############### 1. Generate the data 

flips <- c(sample(c(rep(1,3), rep(0,9))), # coin 1, mint 1, 12 flips total
           sample(c(rep(1,1), rep(0,4))), # coin 2, mint 1, 5 flips total
           sample(c(rep(1,10), rep(0,5))), # coin 1, mint 2, 15 flips
           sample(c(rep(1,17), rep(0,6)))) # coin 2, mint 2, 23 flips

# NOTE: I got rid of `factor` because it was unneeded and got in the way
coins <- c(rep(1,12), rep(2,5), rep(3, 15), rep(4, 23))

# NOTE: I got rid of `factor` because it was unneeded and got in the way
mints <- c(rep(1,17), rep(2,38))

nFlips <- length(flips) 
nCoins <- length(unique(coins))
nMints <- length(unique(mints))

# NEW: Create vector that specifies the mint of each coin. There must be a     more 
# elegant way to do this, but here is a logical brute-force approach. This
# assumes that coins are consecutively numbered from 1 to nCoins.
mintOfCoin = NULL
for ( cIdx in 1:nCoins ) {
  mintOfCoin = c( mintOfCoin , unique(mints[coins==cIdx]) )
}

#################### 2. Pass data into a list 

dataList <- list(
  flips = flips,
  coins = coins,
  mints = mints,
  nFlips = nFlips,
  nCoins = nCoins,
  nMints = nMints,
  mintOfCoin = mintOfCoin # NOTE
  )


################### 3. specify and save the model 

modelString <- "
model{
  # start with nested likelihood function
  for (fIdx in 1:nFlips) {
    flips[fIdx] ~ dbern( theta[coins[fIdx]] )
  } 
  # next the prior on theta
  # NOTE: Here we use the mintOfCoin index.
  for (cIdx in 1:nCoins) {
    theta[cIdx] ~ dbeta( omega[mintOfCoin[cIdx]]*(kappa - 2) + 1 ,
                          ( 1 - omega[mintOfCoin[cIdx]])*(kappa - 2) + 1 ) 
  }
  # next we specify the prior for the higher-level parameters on the mint, 
  # omega and kappa
  # NOTE: I changed the name of the mint index so it doesn't conflict with 
  # mints data vector.
  for (mIdx in 1:nMints) {
    omega[mIdx] ~ dbeta(2,2)
  }
  kappa <- 5
}
"


writeLines(modelString, "tempModelHier4CoinTwoMint.txt")

############################### Step 4: Initialise Chains 

initsList <- list(theta1 = mean(flips[coins==1]),
                  theta2 = mean(flips[coins==2]),
                  theta3 = mean(flips[coins==3]),
                  theta4 = mean(flips[coins==4]),
                  omega1 = mean(c(mean(flips[coins==1]),
                                  mean(flips[coins==2]))),
                  omega2 = mean(c(mean(flips[coins==3]),
                                  mean(flips[coins==4]))))

initsList


############################### Step 5: Generate Chains 

runJagsOut <- run.jags(method = "parallel",
                       model = "tempModelHier4CoinTwoMint.txt",
                       # NOTE: theta and omega are vectors:
                       monitor = c( "theta", "omega" , "kappa" ),
                       data = dataList,
                       #inits = initsList, # NOTE: Let JAGS initialize.
                       n.chains = 4, # NOTE: Not only 1 chain.
                       adapt = 500,
                       burnin = 1000,
                       sample = 10000,
                       thin = 1,
                       summarise = FALSE,
                       plots = FALSE)



############################### Step 6: Convert to Coda Object 

codaSamples <- as.mcmc.list(runJagsOut)

head(codaSamples)

########################################
## NOTE: Important step --- Check MCMC diagnostics 

# Display diagnostics of chain, for specified parameters:
source("DBDA2E-utilities.R") # For function diagMCMC()
parameterNames = varnames(codaSamples) # from coda package
for ( parName in parameterNames ) {
  diagMCMC( codaObject=codaSamples , parName=parName )
}



############################### Step 7: Make Graphs 
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you @ John K. Kruschke. Immensely helpful as always. Love your book by the way.